# Java Stream - String replace if match using Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, iterator, java-stream, refactoring

I have if condition where I am checking for String equality, if they match I store them in Set. Then I am looping through Set to check if `ENUM3` value is present, if yes I replace that particular string with value `String Java` . I am using Iterator to loop and check for equality. I am looking for same functionality with use of streams where

```
1. I can loop through Set
2. Check for String equality
3. If ENUM3 found then replace with Java
4. Save all the matched String
```

Here is my code

```
{
    Set<String> only = new HashSet<String>();
    Iterator<Mark> itr = Marks.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Mark find = itr.next();

        if (ENUM1.getData().equals(find.search())||ENUM3.getData().equals(find.search())) {
            only.add(find.search());
            only = only.stream()
                    .map(macro -> macro.equals(ENUM3.getData()) ? "Java" : macro).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried using Stream

```
only = only.stream()
            .map(macro -> macro.equals(ENUM3.getData()) ? "Java" : macro)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Your logic is a little hard to understand. Why are you looping through `only` in each iteration? Why not do that at the end of the `while` loop?

Comment: Sorry I did not get your question. Basically all I am trying to do is check for string equality by iterating through Set and save the values if they match, also if value matches ENUM3 just replace it with String java. With the above Stream code String replace is possible by I am looking for only use streams to loop through Set and check for String equality, in short replacing Iterator logic with Streams. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should perform your entire operation:

```
Set<String> only = Marks.stream()
    .map(Mark::search)
    .filter(mark -> ENUM1.getData().equals(mark) 
                    || ENUM2.getData().equals(mark) 
                    || ENUM3.getData().equals(mark))
    .map(macro -> macro.equals(ENUM3.getData()) ? "Java" : macro)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You seem to be unnecessarily doing these 2 (both of which are avoided in the pipeline above)

- iterating through `only` in each iteration to replace `ENUM3.getData()` with `Java`
- repeatedly calling `Mark.search()`

Comment: Further `ENUM1.getData().equals(mark) 
                    || ENUM2.getData().equals(mark) 
                    || ENUM3.getData().equals(mark)` could be replaced with a `Set.contains` where the `Set` would include `Enum1,2,3.getData()`.

Comment: It is giving Cannot find symbol ```Mark``` error, on line 2

Comment: @user12707940 `Mark` is used in your original code, so you should have an import for it.

Comment: Yes it is, ```Mark``` is type. But the error is cannot find symbol  variable ```Mark```, not sure why. As ```search``` is a method do I need to add parenthesis like search() ?

Comment: What happens when you replace `Mark::search` with `mark -> mark.search()`?

Comment: Thanks that worked, one more question, need some suggestions on writing test case for this method.

Comment: @user12707940 Mind putting specifics of that in a new question? That would get more attention/answers.

Comment: Hi here is the link for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780621/java-how-to-write-junit-tests-for-resttemplate-postforobject/59781339#59781339